# Why is this SQL summing values that are way too great?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum

I've got this SQL (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056615/how-can-i-loop-through-a-table-within-a-stored-procedure)):

```
declare @Unit varchar(30);
declare @Year int = 2017;
declare @Month int = 3;
declare @paramdate datetime;
set @paramdate = convert(datetime,convert(char(4),@Year)
                +right('0'+convert(varchar(2),@month),2)
                +'01') 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Units', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Units

select distinct unit
into #Units
from ReportingMonthlySales;

select 
    u.Unit
  , New      = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'New'      then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Assumed  = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Assumed'  then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Existing = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Existing' then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Organic  = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Organic'  then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
from #Units u
  left join CustomerCategoryLog ccl 
    on u.Unit = ccl.Unit
   and @paramdate >= ccl.begindate
   and @paramdate <= ccl.enddate OR ccl.enddate is null
  left join ReportingMonthlySales rms
    on u.Unit = rms.Unit
   and rms.cyear  = @year
   and rms.cmonth = @month
group by u.unit;
```

...which (eventually, after much churning) gives me data like this:

[image]

The "Uchi" Unit, for example, shows "New" sales of over a billion dollars and "Existing" sales of 77 million. This is not really so, as this shows:

[image]

If I try to see exactly how much there is for each Subcategory, this way:

```
select monthlysales from ReportingMonthlySales RMS
left join CustomerCategoryLog CCL on RMS.Unit = CCL.Unit
where RMS.unit = 'Uchi' and CYear = 2017 and cmonth = 3 and Subcategory = 'New'
--where RMS.unit = 'Uchi' and CYear = 2017 and cmonth = 3 and Subcategory = 'Existing'
--where RMS.unit = 'Uchi' and CYear = 2017 and cmonth = 3 and Subcategory = 'Assumed'
--where RMS.unit = 'Uchi' and CYear = 2017 and cmonth = 3 and Subcategory = 'Organic'
--where RMS.unit = 'Uchi' and CYear = 2017 and cmonth = 3 and Subcategory = 'Exploding'
```

...I end up with "0 items" regardless of which Subcategory value I query for. Even this WHERE clause:

```
where RMS.unit = 'Uchi' and Subcategory = 'New'
```

...turns up nothing.

Why is the sum so astronomical? How can I get it to calculate a more reasonable value (preferaby the right one), and not only extremes of either nothing or "everything"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOIN` condition is matching multiple rows.  That *might* be a property of the data, but your `ON` clause is problematic.  You have:

```
on u.Unit = ccl.Unit and
   @paramdate >= ccl.begindate and
   @paramdate <= ccl.enddate OR ccl.enddate is null
```

You intend:

```
on u.Unit = ccl.Unit and
   @paramdate >= ccl.begindate and
   (@paramdate <= ccl.enddate OR ccl.enddate is null)
```

Comment: That helped; I still have some doubtlessly bogus values, though, such as over 2 billions in that one month for Applebees, etc. I'll czech it out more thoroughly tomorrow.