# Why do these sum operations not "add up" as they should?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Note: This is a follow[on,up] to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056615/how-can-i-loop-through-a-table-within-a-stored-procedure) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775198/how-can-i-add-four-calculated-values-to-a-result-set-from-a-stored-proc-tsql) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057989/why-is-this-sql-summing-values-that-are-way-too-great).

The responses all moved me forward, but even that last one, although it improved matters, did not completely solve this issue.

This query:

```
select monthlysales, MemberNo from ReportingMonthlySales
where unit = 'Abuelos' and CYear = 2017 and cmonth = 3
```

...returns a bunch of rows, where the Monthly Sales total is $364,121.69

However, when I try to compartmentalize these monthly sales into four categories, although the sum of them all should be the same, the sum is actually astronomically "huger" - the following code returns the vastly inflated value of 23,924,211.30

24 millions of dollars is almost 70 times as much as the 364 thousand that is the actual sum total. Why is this "crazy" inflation occurring?

Here is the fancy pants but apparently bamboozled code:

```
declare @Unit varchar(30);
declare @Year int = 2017;
declare @Month int = 3;
declare @paramdate datetime;
set @paramdate = convert(datetime,convert(char(4),@Year)
                +right('0'+convert(varchar(2),@month),2)
                +'01') 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Units', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Units

select distinct unit
into #Units
from ReportingMonthlySales;

select 
    u.Unit
  , New      = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'New'      then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Assumed  = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Assumed'  then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Existing = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Existing' then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Organic  = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Organic'  then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
from #Units u
  left join CustomerCategoryLog ccl 
    on u.Unit = ccl.Unit
   and @paramdate >= ccl.begindate and
   (@paramdate <= ccl.enddate OR ccl.enddate is null)
  left join ReportingMonthlySales rms
    on u.Unit = rms.Unit
   and rms.cyear  = @year
   and rms.cmonth = @month
group by u.unit;

The two tables queried are:

CustomerCategoryLog
-------------------
MemberNo (VarChar)
Unit (VarChar)
Custno (VarChar)
Category (VarChar)
Subcategory (VarChar)
BeginDate (DateTime)
EndDate (DateTime)
ChangedBy (VarChar)
ChangedOn (DateTime)

ReportingMonthlySales
---------------------
AutoID (Int)
Unit (VarChar)
MemberNo (VarChar)
NumUnits (Int)
MonthlySales (Money)
CYear (Int)
Cmonth (Int)
CreateDate (DateTime)
```

Is there something faulty in the fancy-pants sql, or ... ?!?

Comment: I bet if you remove the sum parts of the query and just add a couple of other columns to see the actual result set (such as Id column), you'll notice that your query's result set is repeating the rows, which means your joins need more fine tuning.

Comment: Agree with @Sparrow especially since CustomerCategoryLog seems to be a log table and likely leads to a one to many join.

Comment: Also run this and let us know how many rows are returned - ```select * from CustomerCategoryLog where unit = 'Abuelos'```

Comment: Look at the join between CustomerCategoryLog AND ReportingMonthlySales. The breakdown by Subcategory is part of the CustomerCategoryLog, but unless Unit is unique between them, there is no actual correlation between a single row in the CCL table and a single row in the RMS table. Odds are that you need to join the customer to the Automobile he purchased, then join that to the ReportingMonthlySales table to correctly break things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the left joins and `Or ccl.enddate is null` generated a 1 to many

Perhaps a straight inner join will correct the inflation

```
select 
    u.Unit
  , New      = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'New'      then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Assumed  = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Assumed'  then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Existing = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Existing' then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
  , Organic  = sum(case when ccl.Subcategory = 'Organic'  then rms.MonthlySales else 0 end)
from #Units u
join CustomerCategoryLog   ccl on u.Unit = ccl.Unit and @paramdate >= ccl.begindate and @paramdate <= ccl.enddate
join ReportingMonthlySales rms on u.Unit = rms.Unit and rms.cyear  = @year and rms.cmonth = @month
group by u.unit;
```

Comment: That looks a heck of a lot more like it.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Congrats on having a sense of what your results should be.  I once witness our TECH support not even blink at $17.8 TRILLION in Net Interest Income for the MONTH

Comment: Data is correct - thanks! This not only broke my head - a soon-to-be-ex-programmer - but even those of some sqlheads. Granted (no pun intended), they did not have access to the database to see the actual data.

Comment: Thanks - you might, then, be interested in my collection of his witticisms, aphorisms, and criticisms. The Twain museum in Redding, CT (Twain's last residence) is using it as their gift to guest speakers.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon That was a nice little surprise, and certainly not necessary, but I do appreciate the consideration   -  Thank you

Comment: No problem - I'm in the "Andrew Carnegie" mode of my SO life. Also, it appeals to my quirky sense of humor to have more badges than reputation points. Even when I quit programming (two weeks from today), I will look back in from time to time, and give away any points I've accumulated in the meanwhile.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon  "Andrew Carnegie" mode ... that was funny.  My next career will be custom furniture.   Horse Farm, to Hotel, to Banking, to Consulting... next will be ME TIME.   Looking forward to being that odd fellow with sawdust in his beard.

Comment: I have sometimes been tempted to go into banking, John Dillinger-style.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a join between the RMS table and these other tables.  Your code assumes it will find one record for each record in the RMS table.  This is not true.  This is the cause of getting multiple rows reported and summed.  I would think it is most likely that for a particular unit and @paramdate, there is multiple CCL entries.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is causing the duplication

```
select distinct unit
into #Units
from ReportingMonthlySales;
```

you basically inserted the same data from the table and used at the left join..

try this updated script

```
  SELECT
  rms.Unit,
  New = SUM(CASE
    WHEN ccl.Subcategory = 'New' THEN rms.MonthlySales
    ELSE 0
  END),
  Assumed = SUM(CASE
    WHEN ccl.Subcategory = 'Assumed' THEN rms.MonthlySales
    ELSE 0
  END),
  Existing = SUM(CASE
    WHEN ccl.Subcategory = 'Existing' THEN rms.MonthlySales
    ELSE 0
  END),
  Organic = SUM(CASE
    WHEN ccl.Subcategory = 'Organic' THEN rms.MonthlySales
    ELSE 0
  END)
FROM ReportingMonthlySales rms
inner JOIN CustomerCategoryLog ccl
  ON rms.Unit = ccl.Unit
where
  AND @paramdate >= ccl.begindate
  AND (@paramdate <= isnull(ccl.enddate,getdate())
  )
 AND
   rms.cyear = @year
  AND rms.cmonth = @month
GROUP BY rms.unit;
```

Comment: This also gives the humongous results - almost 3 billion dollars for Applebees for a single month. That's a lot of riblets!

Comment: @B.ClayShannon haha.. i missed the join.. should be inner

Answer (score 0):

Your CustomerCategoryTable as what its name implies could have multiple records for different CustNo for the same UnitNo and that makes your first left join returns duplicate rows which will multiplies the monthly sales, and what I think is that there is no solution for your query except if you try to fix the schema itself for one simple information is that you are trying to find the monthly sales for each unit for it's different subcategorues and your ReportingMonthlySales table doesn't have any information regarding the subcategories.